# Print Max and Min Value in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have just started practicing on HackerRank to improve my coding skills. I'm mostly using Java as my preferred language. I have got this question, and I have tried my level best to give the solution but didn't clear all the test cases. **I have cleared 5 out 15 test cases**, but still 10 cases are left to be done. Those who are on the hackerrank can see the question by following this link : [Min-Max Sum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem)

I'm anyway giving the brief description of the question :

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

For example,`arr=[1,3,5,7,9]`. Our minimum sum is `1+3+5+7=16` and our maximum sum is `3+5+7+9=24`. We would print `16 24`

**Output Format**

Print two space-separated long integers denoting the respective minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. (The output can be greater than a 32 bit integer.)

**Sample Input**  `1 2 3 4 5`

**Sample Output** `10 14`

**Explanation**

Our initial numbers are `1, 2, 3, 4, and 5`. We can calculate the following sums using four of the five integers:

```
If we sum everything except 1, our sum is 2+3+4+5=14.
If we sum everything except 2, our sum is 1+3+4+5=13.
If we sum everything except 3, our sum is 1+2+4+5=12.
If we sum everything except 4, our sum is 1+2+3+5=11.
If we sum everything except 5, our sum is 1+2+3+4=10.
```

**My Algo**

```
  for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    totSum += arr[i];
  }

  sumOne = totSum - arr[0];
  sumTwo = totSum - arr[1];
  sumThree = totSum - arr[2];
  sumFour = totSum - arr[3];
  sumFive = totSum - arr[4];

  int[] num = {sumOne, sumTwo, sumThree, sumFour, sumFive};
  int temp = 0;
  for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<(num.length-i);j++){
        if(num[j-1] > num[j]){  
            //swap elements  
            temp = num[j-1];  
            num[j-1] = num[j];  
            num[j] = temp;  
        }
    }
  }

  System.out.print(num[0] + " " + num[4]);
```

We can also do that by iterating through the `num array`, and finding the max and min value.

But somehow after all doing this, I don't clear this module.

**Please Note :** The number of elements in arr is fixed that is 5 only.

I have got to know that amongst the 10 fails, I got to know about one test case, which is like this :

**Input(stdin)**
`256741038 623958417 467905213 714532089 938071625`

**Expected Output**
`2063136757 2744467344`

Comment: What help do you exactly need?

Comment: I;m trying to figure out that why my code is failing for the rest 10 cases @MaruthiAdithya. Since you know that we cannot see all the test cases results, however, I have added one input which raised a query, and failed my code. See in the last line.

Comment: @Alok Change `int`  to `long int` or even try `long long int`

Comment: But don't you think sorting will also give my answer, since in the print I have taken the first element as min, and the last element is max. Doesn't make any difference @NomanKhan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea (although sorting the array is a bit of an overkill, since you just need its maximum and minimum values), but when you sum these large integers, you [overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) the `sumtot` variable and get a wrong answer. Using `long`s instead should solve the issue:

```
long totSum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    totSum += arr[i];
}

long sumOne = totSum - arr[0];
long sumTwo = totSum - arr[1];
long sumThree = totSum - arr[2];
long sumFour = totSum - arr[3];
long sumFive = totSum - arr[4];

long[] num = {sumOne, sumTwo, sumThree, sumFour, sumFive};
long temp = 0;
for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<(num.length-i);j++){
        if(num[j-1] > num[j]){
            //swap elements
            temp = num[j-1];
            num[j-1] = num[j];
            num[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}

System.out.print(num[0] + " " + num[4]);
```

Note, BTW, that using Java 8's streams you can implement the same logic and save a lot of the boilerplate code, as well of the O(nlog(n)) sorting:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(arr).summaryStatistics();

System.out.println
    ((stats.getSum() - stats.getMax()) + " " + (stats.getSum() - stats.getMin()));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use long, as the sum of values can extrapolate the integer max value.
Then, you don't need the double loop and you're probably failing some performance test cases due to that. See this solution which does 2 separated loops for a 2N solution.

```
package minmaxsum;

public class MinMaxSum {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MinMaxSum mms = new MinMaxSum();
    mms.printMinMaxSum(new int[] {256741038, 623958417, 467905213, 714532089, 938071625});

    // mms.printMinMaxSum(new int[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9});
  }

  public void printMinMaxSum(int[] arr) {
    long totalSum = 0;
    for (int num : arr) {
      totalSum += num;
    }

    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long max = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int num : arr) {
      long currentSum = totalSum - num;

      min = Math.min(min, currentSum);
      max = Math.max(max, currentSum);
    }

    System.out.println(min + " " + max);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey I somehow got your code's point, but I'd like to ask one question, that in first place when the second loop starts, what is the value that goes into the min, and max variables or let me know how this min = Long.MAX_VALUE, and max = Long.MIN_VALUE makes sense? Thanks

Comment: min starts with the maximum possible value for a long variable. That way, when it's compared against any other number, like 50L, it will be guaranteed that it will be replaced by that value. The idea is that we'll loop through the values and properly set min and max along the way.

Answer (score 1):

This works for all  test cases. Just submitted the code

```
 static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
         Arrays.sort(arr);
            long minSum=0,maxSum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
               minSum+=arr[i];
               maxSum+=arr[arr.length-1-i] ;
            }
            System.out.println(minSum + " " + maxSum);

    }
```

Not all test cases have sorted data.
Once array is sorted single loop is enough to calculate min and max sum. 
Sorting helped to reduce time complexity from O(n*n)  to O(nlogn)

Comment: I have tried doing it my in my way, that is `looping upto arr.length`, it gives me wrong answer. Why is it happening. So according to the statement I understand that minSum is the sum of the all the expect the max num, and vice versa for maxSum. So what I have done is looping upto `arr.length`, and initializing the `minsum += arr[i];`, and `maxSum += arr[i+1]`. It throws `arrayoutofboundexception`. Since sorted array consist of the element which are sorted from right to left. Could you please help me on that?

Comment: Expected output  is sum of 4 elements.  Loop from 0 to arr.length-1 will result in  sum  of 5 numbers ,  hence wrong answer.  Also if you loop from 0 to arr.length than maxSum += arr[i+1] will result in arrayoutofbound  when  value of i  reaches array.length-1.

Comment: I have found out the way, and got your point also , however, I have made the sum of max simpler, as looping through the array till `arr.length-1`, will give the `minSum += arr[i]`, however we actually don't need to follow the step for maxSum which you have suggested that is `arr[arr.length-1-i]`. `maxsum += arr[i+1]` will also do the job

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to change the way of thinking: as a programmer usually is better to think like the machine than a human.

Ask yourself, what would be the maximumSum of an array without one element? And the answer is the sum of all elements except the maximum value element. So, if you simply find the element with the maximum value, and sum the rest elements it's the first part of the solution. Exactly the same logic is applicable to minimumSum...

Thinking this way reduce the effort and time to solve the problem.

For example - in one loop find the maximumElement and minimumElement.

In second loop sum the both results - `sumMax += array[index]` avoiding the index of maximumElement; `sumMin += array[index]` avoiding the index of minimumElement.

Of course everything of above can be done in just one loop, but since this is your task to improve your programming skills, I'll leave it to you (as well as writing the code).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm to solve this problem.

**Algorithm-**

**Step-1** we are going to find a minimum element in the array.

**Step-2** we will find the maximum element in the array.

**step-3** we are going to calculate the sum of all the elements in the array.

**Step-4** we are calculating the minsum by subtracting max value from total sum in the array.

**Step-5** we are calculating the maxsum by subtracting min value from the overall sum.

And finally, we are going to print minsum and maxsum.

and here is the implementation of this algorithm.

```
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
        long min = 0, max = 0, sum = 0;
        min = arr[0];
        max = min;
        sum = min;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
            if (arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
            }
            if (arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.print((sum - max) + " " + (sum - min));

    }
```

I hope it will help.but still you need more explanation then you can refer this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/CNL1WzrtxGY).